# How to get ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange to Communicate with Task Field

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am currently trying to use a ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange application in a class module to pull resource and assignment costs into a task field. I am doing this because I want to group resource loads on a task into labor and material buckets. I have received some great guidance on how to use a ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange application to isolate an assignment change and react to it. I am now trying to make a link between this application and the ability to parse and sum data in a task.Cost# field.

Currently, the class module prints a lot of helpful information into the immediate window. **Can someone please recommend how to sum `Cost = Assgn.Cost` as it loops and route it to tsk.Cost5 (for my purposes)?** I have tested multiple approaches to this problem and all failed. It appears that the assignment change event does not acknowledge task objects.

ThisProject:

```
Private Sub Project_Open(ByVal pj As Project)

Call m_Events.StartEvents

End Sub
```

m_Event as a regular module:

```
Public oMSPEvents As New cm_Events
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Sub StartEvents()

    Set oMSPEvents.MyMSPApp = Application ' MSProject.Application
    EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

cm_Events Class Module:

```
Private Sub MyMSPApp_ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange(ByVal Assgn As Assignment, ByVal Field As PjAssignmentField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
'
'Dim tsk As task

If Assgn.Resource.Text2 = "Labor" Then
    Cost = Assgn.Cost
    Debug.Print Now, Assgn.ResourceName, Assgn.Resource.Text2, NewVal, "$" & Cost, Assgn
    
End If
      
    If EnableEvents Then
        EnableEvents = False
        
'        tsk.Cost5 = 10
'
'        Dim Assgn As Assignment
'        For Each Assgn In tsk.Assignments
'            If Assgn.Resource.Text1 = "Labor" Then
'                tsk.Cost5 = tsk.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost
'                Assgn.Cost5 = Assgn.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost
'            End If
'        Next Assgn
'
        EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the code works fine but one has to remember that the event is ***before*** change so if the change affects the cost and then the event runs which propagates that cost to the task level, the cost values propagated are the original values, not the new values.

Comment: @RachelHettinger, how could I best capture the "old" value of the field I change during the event with this code above? I want to create two variables: one as NewVal, which I already have, and another as OldVal, so I could compare the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Goal:** Capture changes to assignment-level cost changes and roll them into the task's Cost5 field

**Issue:** While the event, ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange, can be used to react to assignment-level changes, the Cost field is calculated so changes to it are done indirectly, for example, by changing the amount of work. Therefore, the event handler needs to react to changes to any field that would change the assignment cost.

Here is an example of how to use the ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange event to monitor changes to the assignment work to update the task's Cost5 field:

```
Private Sub MyMSPApp_ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange(ByVal asg As Assignment, ByVal Field As PjAssignmentField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

    If EnableEvents And Field = pjAssignmentWork Then
        EnableEvents = False
        
        Dim tsk As Task
        Set tsk = asg.Task
        
        Dim resRate As Double
        resRate = CDbl(Mid(asg.Resource.StandardRate, 2, InStr(asg.Resource.StandardRate, "/") - 2))
        
        Dim newAsnCost As Variant
        newAsnCost = NewVal * resRate
        If asg.Resource.Text1 = "Labor" Then
            tsk.Cost5 = newAsnCost
        Else
            tsk.Cost5 = 0
        End If
        
        Dim Assgn As Assignment
        For Each Assgn In tsk.Assignments
            If Assgn.Resource.Text1 = "Labor" And Assgn <> asg Then
                tsk.Cost5 = tsk.Cost5 + Assgn.Cost
            End If
        Next Assgn

        EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Note: the resRate calculation is based on the Standard Rate having format like "$123.45/hr"; adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Wiki article. It will show you how to do it.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32051.ms-project-extra-fields-in-views.aspx

Comment: thank you! The challenge I am trying to overcome includes not iterating through ever task in the file, but rather making changes on selected tasks after a change to the task's resource assignment.

Comment: BP130, You're welcome. After I posted I realized my "answer" was for a different aspect of the issue but I decided to leave it as reference information.